# PHP variable access across the files

Tags: php

I want to get one page variable values to another page. Is it possible to do with $GLOBALS? or else how should i do? I have a variable

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I want to access $url from another file.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most common way is to store it is a $_SESSION, $GLOBALS won't persist between your pages.

**An example of Session usage**

`$_SESSION['url'] = $url;` or `$_SESSION['url'] = 'http:// . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

As long as your session is initiated you'll have access, and for large amounts of data, you may want to serialize it before moving it to a Session.

Comment: can't we use $GLOBALS

Comment: No you can't use $GLOBALS across page views.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, maybe I am mistaken, but $GLOBALS persist for the length of the script, so you can keep if you pass them to some form of storage like a session, or a frameworks persistence method, right? Else, they end with the script?

Comment: Yes, $GLOBALS don't solve this problem, sessions do, whether you use globals or not.